# What app do i need to have in order to tether from camera to laptop for viewing purposes only?

Tags: canon, tethering

I am looking for an app so I can tether my canon rebel t6i to my laptop for the purpose of just being able to view the photos I take, as I take them, but on a bigger screen. Also, are there changes I will need to make on my camera or my laptop and since I am in the process of purchasing a new laptop, do you have any recommendations knowing I will be using it mainly for tethering, editing photos, and photo storage etc?

Comment: You can get around all this by just buying an EyeFi card.

Comment: @Itai that's a perfectly valid answer, so why comment instead of answer?

Comment: Why buy an EyeFi when the T6i has built-in wifi and comes with all the software you need to tether the camera to a computer?

Comment: @scottbb - Thanks but I would consider it a workaround, rather than tethering :)

Comment: Oh... by "tethering", the OP wanted to tether. Gotcha. =)  sorry, nevermind! (note to self: RTFQ.)

Comment: It's still tethering, even if the connection is via WiFi rather than a wired cable.

Comment: @user49786 Your question would be much more answerable if you would specify the OS you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Beside EOS Utility there are other free alternatives with improved preview possibility like [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) for Windows or [Sofortbild](http://www.sofortbildapp.com/) for Mac

In [Tether Tools](https://www.tethertools.com/tethering-software/) site there is a comprehensive list of available tether software.

Answer (score 2):

Canon has a software program for your computer called "EOS Utility" that will do everything you want and more. There are no changes required to the camera or computer.

It comes on the CD with your camera or can be downloaded from Canon. Look for "software" under "Drivers and Downloads":  [EOS Utility Download](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/cameras/dslr/eos-rebel-t6i-ef-s-18-55mm-is-stm)

Comment: It's nice to note the supported operating systems for stuff like this... in this case, it appears to be Windows (7 or higher) only.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle By default the link shows results based on the OS of the computer from which you are accessing it. All of Canon's tools are also compatible with contemporary versions of the Mac platforms as well. If you're using a Linux environment then surely you have either a virtual machine Windows or virtual machine Mac application installed.

Comment: @MichaelClark - I tried selecting what I thought were contemporary Mac versions on the page, must have misssed the right one.